# Redirect - перенаправление

Tags: wordpress

Возможно-ли методом PHP в вордпресс, сделать Redirect публикаций-статей из определенной рубрики на заданную страницу. Хочу заметить, что таких рубрик со статьями и станиц, куда нужно сделать Redirect - много.

То-есть:

```
рубрика cat=1 (все статьи) Redirect на https://syte.ru/?page_id=8
рубрика cat=2 (все статьи) Redirect на https://syte.ru/?page_id=11
рубрика cat=3 (все статьи) Redirect на https://syte.ru/?page_id=14
рубрика cat=4 (все статьи) Redirect на https://syte.ru/?page_id=17
```

И т.д

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Я бы воспользовался хуком `template_redirect`, добавив в него условие или использовал бы плагин Redirection - https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: @mihdanВ плагине есть возможность указать редирект для группы статей прикрепленных к катнгории? Если такой возможности нет, то смысл теряется. Три тысячи статей лопатить в ручную - бред.

Answer (score 0):

**Это решение рабочее, возможно кому-то поможет.**

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'post_redirect_by_custom_filters');
function post_redirect_by_custom_filters() {
    global $post;
    // этот массив может содержать имена категорий, и идентификаторы.
    $catArray = ['1'];
    if (is_single($post->ID) && has_category($catArray, $post)) {
        $new_url = "https://syte.ru/?page_id=8{$post->post_name}/";  
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

На странице рубрики и странице статьи добавьте условие, код будет работать если у вас в URL присутствует параметр `cat`:

```
switch ($_GET['cat']){
    case 1:
            header('Location: https://syte.ru/?page_id=8',true, 301);
            exit;
            break;
    case 2:
            header('Location: https://syte.ru/?page_id=11',true, 301);
            exit;
            break;
    default:
        //Если ни одно из условий не соблюдено, стандартное действие
}
```

В условие `switch` не обязательно добавлять `GET`, можно использовать `get_the_category()`:

```
$category = get_the_category();
switch ($category[0]->cat_ID){
    case 1:
            header('Location: https://syte.ru/?page_id=8',true, 301);
            exit;
            break;
    case 2:
            header('Location: https://syte.ru/?page_id=11',true, 301);
            exit;
            break;
    default:
        //Если ни одно из условий не соблюдено, стандартное действие
}
```

Comment: @ДмитрийГорныйПростите. Что-то не понимаю, что значит: "На странице рубрики и странице статьи добавьте условие". Вы имеете в виду: "Для страницЫ рубрики и страниц статьи, добавьте условие".

Comment: В целом это и имел ввиду, у wordpress есть php файлы, которые отвечают за вывод рубрик и статей именно в них нужно добавить условие, чтобы условие не обрабатывалось на всех страницах сайта.

Comment: @ДмитрийГорныйТак как я не близко дружу с php, могли-бы вы уточнить, в каких именно файлах размещать. Или-же упирается в то, что эти файлы в теме, а как известно во многих темах это индивидуально.

Comment: Обычно можно проверить var_dump'ом, т.е. вы заходите в php файл шаблона схожего по названию со страницей и выводите var_dump. Таким образом вы определите какие файлы отвечают за какие страницы. А вообще, если вы не сильны в PHP, то лучше используйте плагины, как вам посоветовал @mihdan в комментариях выше.